# Mirror remote mailbox (gmail) locally

Tags: backup, imap, gmail, mirror

Is there an easy way to mirror my gmail mailbox to a local (linux) server?

Due to the number of clients at home (phone, tablets, etc) I keep hitting the gmail imap connection limit. Also would be good to have a backup of my mail locally just in case.

Comment: You might be looking for imapsync : http://imapsync.lamiral.info

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Valentin kindly took time to give you indications on your home problem. Feel free to ask questions here if "it is not about anything in a home setting" http://serverfault.com/faq. I'll suggest this question to be migrated to superuser.com .

Answer (score 1):

As Eric already commented, imapsync could be a solution for you. With imapsync you would be able to mirror your  mails into a local mail box (e.g. provided by cyrus).

Unfortunately all your calender entries, contacts etc will not be affected when using imapsync. However, having access to your mails locally should be sufficient.

You can learn more about ImapSync here:
[Official ImapSync website](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)

This Google search should help you with your migration:
[Quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=imapsync%20from%20gmail%20to)